# how to implement card viewer with swipe event in xamarin.forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I want to create a card-viewer in xamarin.forms which will be bind with a list of custom class.It needs to support swipe event.After each swipe next item of list will be binded in a card view.

I am unable to track the swipe event.There is a ready-made solution of this by using MGesture but I don't want to do this I want to create my own control.

If anybody has worked on cardView control and swipe gesture please help me?

Comment: It may be helpfull: http://chrisriesgo.com/xamarin-forms-carousel-view-recipe/

Comment: Does this need to be for iOS, Android, and Windows Phone?

Comment: Yes,I need this for all these platforms.

Comment: This is carousel control,I need something similar to this but the new page will come up as a card view after swipe only.So my main challenge is to implement swipe event.

Comment: I have achieved this by using MR gesture nuggets.

Comment: Checkout - https://github.com/xamarinhq/app-evolve